# Travis: Deploy after merging pull request into master

Tags: git, github, npm, travis-ci, devops

Let's say I have `release-1.0.0` branch, and I want to create a pull request into master for this branch. After creating pull request Travis starts checks and run build script.

If everything is ok, github gives me a green flag and allows me to merge release branch into master. I merge release branch into master and now I want deploy to start (to npm, and to github releases).

And I want to deploy to github releases using git tag, but when I merge pr to master I lose my tag and I get something like this: **Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this is not a tagged commit**.
Any ideas of how I can do it for my git flow?
This is my config:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - lts/*
install:
- npm ci
- npm install -g codecov
script:
- npm run build 
- ./node_modules/.bin/nyc report --reporter lcovonly -- -R spec 
- codecov
branches:
  only: 
    - master
deploy:
  - provider: releases
    skip_cleanup: true
    api_key:
    secure: *****
    file: 'README.md'
    on:
      tags: true
      repo: name_of_repo
      branch: master
  - provider: npm
    email: email@email.com
    api_key:
      secure: *****
      on:
        tags: true
        repo: name_of_repo
        branch: master
```

Comment: You could have a tag created when a successful merge into master is completed, then when a tag is created on master, have another build start running a deploy only. I don't know if there is a way to do this all through the pull request from what I've been reading so far. I'm also interested in doing this soon, great question

Comment: TravisCI GitHub Release documentation says [you can set the tag at deploy time](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/#setting-the-tag-at-deployment-time)

Comment: Was that the fix?

Comment: I chose a different approach. I deploy my master if last commit message matches reqex: `^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$`, and then I use a tag name in deploy as `tag_name: $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE`

Comment: @SpencerPollock If you are still interested, I wrote an article about how I control quality of npm packages via Travis CI (https://guseyn.com/posts/travis-control-quality?v=1.0.90)